# DataGridView add row from different class

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to add a new row to a DataGridView from another class.

It works in the same class:

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] columns = { "Column A", "Column B" };
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (string column in columns)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(column, typeof(string));
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}

public void AddRow(string[] row)
{
    DataTable dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

private void buttonAddRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] results = new string[] { "result 1", "result 2" };
    AddRow(results);
}
```

But if I call **AddRow()** from another class, it throws an exception:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

dt was null.

```
class Test
{
    public void CreateRows()
    {
        string[] results = new string[] { "result 1", "result 2" };
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.AddRow(results);
    }
```

What is the best way to add a row from another class? Thanks for help.

Comment: required reading **[new operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator)** it is called `new` for a very good reason - it creates a *new* object.

Comment: After a closer look. The code in the `Test` class method `CreateRows` is not doing what you think it is. The code “creates” a NEW `Form1`, calls the `form1.AddRow..` method, then exits. This form is NEVER displayed to the user. You are getting a `null` exception on the line… `dt.Rows.Add(row);` because `dt` doesn’t have any rows yet. Calling the forms constructor `Form1 form1 = new Form1();` does not fire the forms `Load` event. The forms `Load` event is fired when it is displayed, which it never is.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this is one of the solutions:

```
private static Form1 instance;
public static Form1 ReturnInstance()
{
    return instance;
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    instance = this;
}

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] columns = { "Column A", "Column B" };
    foreach (string column in columns)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column, column);
    }
}

public void AddRow(string[] row)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

```
public class Test
{
    public void CreateRows()
    {
        string[] results = new string[] { "result 1", "result 2" };
        Form1 form1 = Form1.ReturnInstance();
        form1.AddRow(results);
    }
}
```

Now I'm looking for a solution how to add a row using the async method